# PHP & MySQL - Error Question

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how can I stop PHP & MySQL errors from displaying to users but still have the errors logged in the server so I know something is wrong.

Comment: good question and stupid answers. display_errors=off log_errors=on. that's all. not a rocket science.

Comment: however, mysql errors is another matter. Use trigger_error() function to convert them into regular PHP errors. run all your queries this way: `$res = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);`

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel is there a way to turn off mysql errors from php.ini .htaccess or something.

Comment: there is nothing to turn off. Go figure. there are no special mysql errors in PHP. just regular PHP errors

Comment: Aw, I am lying! Just recalled that PHP has some ini setting - `mysql.trace_mode` which is off by default, however. and it can supply you with some useful hints, so, it's better to be turned on. Anyway, it has nothing to do with "display vs. log" problem.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel what about if I'm not using `trigger_error()`  and using only print mysqli_error($mysqli); will errors still be turned of using PHP?

Comment: that's quite lame question, my boy. print operator is intended to print things. **So, change your prints to trigger_error** and stop talking that nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

two ways:

- Config your php.ini (turn error off)
- Put a @ after any action...

Example:

```
<?php
 $a = @mysq_query("a bad query");
 echo @$b; // $b donst exist, so thrwos an error but with the @ dosnt show anything
?>
```

Comment: Open your php.ini search for... display_errors = On, change the "On" for "Off"

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that there is a good reason to surpress MySQL Errors. If there error gives away too much info about your database set up and schema (by showing the query in the error... joins... etc.) you don't want a live site showing those errors to the public. Of course you would want to log them. So in the interest of security this is a good single reason to not display them on a live site. As I said logging yes. Displaying no.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Set [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to zero and define a log file with [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) in your php.ini or with [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) or something.

Comment: @Ben there is nothing to suppress actually. if you don't want mysql errors to be displayed - do not display it. As simple as that

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, It is true that `mysql_query` doesn't throw any errors or warnings, however `mysql_connect`, `mysql_fetch_assoc` and several others `mysql` functions do. That's why, if you only want to suppress `mysql` warnings/errors, user `or log_function()` along with the `@`.

Comment: @Ben these are regular PHP errors and there are not a single reason to treat it any special way. And the OP never talked of suppressing anything. It's just a nonsense. No error message should be suppressed.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I don't see the problem of hiding a warning telling me `Acces denied for user 'user'@'host'` (I don't wan't anyone to know what my DB host or user is) and telling the user in a friendly way "Hey! something bad happened" while logging the error. It sure is better than the plain old black and white screen that scares people away.

Comment: @Ben So I do. But it has nothing to do with suppressing anything.

Comment: @TIERED: yes, that's where they go. But as I said, you can use ini_set() as well.

Comment: Btw.: If you don't like the question then down-vote that, and not my answer, because there's nothing wrong with it. Thank you.